# Is there a super partition on Pixel 3/3XL with Android 10 (or greater) loaded?

Tags: fastboot, partitions, android-10, google-pixel

**Question:** Does a production Pixel 3/3XL have a super partition when loaded with Android 10 or greater?

**Background:**

I changed out the UFS piece on a Pixel 3XL and loaded the newest Android 10 and 11 beta factory images for Pixel 3XL (crosshatch). In both Android 10 and 11 beta, when I use "fastboot getvar all" in bootloader or fastbootd mode, there is no super partition listed. However, according to the BoardConfig-common.mk file, it looks like the device should have a super partition:

```
ifeq ($(PRODUCT_USE_DYNAMIC_PARTITIONS), true)
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_GROUPS := google_dynamic_partitions
BOARD_GOOGLE_DYNAMIC_PARTITIONS_PARTITION_LIST := \
    system \
    vendor \
    product

ifeq ($(PRODUCT_RETROFIT_DYNAMIC_PARTITIONS), true)
# Normal Pixel 3 must retrofit dynamic partitions.
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_SIZE := 4072669184
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_METADATA_DEVICE := system
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_BLOCK_DEVICES := system vendor product
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_SYSTEM_DEVICE_SIZE := 2952790016
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_VENDOR_DEVICE_SIZE := 805306368
BOARD_SUPER_PARTITION_PRODUCT_DEVICE_SIZE := 314572800
# Assume 4MB metadata size.
# TODO(b/117997386): Use correct metadata size.
BOARD_GOOGLE_DYNAMIC_PARTITIONS_SIZE := 4069523456
else
# Mainline Pixel 3 has an actual super partition.
```

I've followed all instructions on [the Implementing Dynamic Partitions page](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/dynamic_partitions/implement). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is no super partition on a pixel 3/3xl, the device is retrofit to be able to work, but still no super partition: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/dynamic_partitions/ab_legacy#background